# UITableViewCell - ContentView overlapping when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, overlapping

I have added a UILabel as the content view of my tableview. The text in the UILabel is overlapping upon scrolling. Below is the code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.chatTableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Group"];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Group";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.chatTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                                                     forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = self.latestTrimText;

    UILabel *cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    cellLabel.text = self.dateOfLatestTrim;
    cellLabel.frame = CGRectMake(15, 0, 150, 30);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cellLabel];

    return cell;
}
```

I can fix this by changing to `UITableViewCell *cell = [self.chatTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];`

But then, the scrolling of the tableview won't be smooth. Is there another way to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The tableview cells are recycled and reused potentially an infinite amount of times. This is what the reuse identifier stands for.

Take care not to add any subview outside the if (cell==nil) block. Now you are just adding again and again a new label to the same cell instance. This is why your texts overlaps each other.

I would recommend you to read the documentation on how the cells are recycled and reused.

Your fix is not correct because by passing a nil reuse id, you are just preventing the recycling process to play. You create a new instance for each row of your tableview. This is why you have performance issues then.